# How to highlight the selected tabs in php?

Tags: php, database, function

```
<?php
        include("admin/db.php");

        echo '<div class="rmm"><ul id="nav">

        <li class="home"><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>

        <li class="about"><a href="aboutus.php"><span>About Us</span></a></li>';
        $sql="SELECT * FROM category WHERE 1";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<li class="'.$row['cname'].'">'."<a href='category.php?id=".$row["cid"]."'>".$row['cname']."</a></li>"  ;
        }
        echo '<li class="level2 nav-2-3-2"><a href="contactus.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li></ul></div>';
    ?>
```

I am having menus page like this. I want to highlight the tabs if it gets select option.Suppose if i have different page for each menu. I can use id for each page.But here I don't have idea..Can anyone explain answer with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way. You get (`$_GET`) the ID of the category query string (if any) and see if it's the same as the one that we're currently printing on the list. If it is, then give it some different effect, which highlights the link as "currently open" by setting the ID of the link as "current", which is a style defined in the stylesheet code, now you have a highlighted link.

The advantage of this technique is that you don't need to worry about JavaScript compatibility as the highlight is printed to the HTML file itself, this way it's considered as native code and will run flawlessly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: #151515;
            }

            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }

            li {
                margin: 15px;
            }

            a {
                padding: 5px 10px;
                color: #151515;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a:hover {
                color: #FEFEFE;
                background-color: #151515;
            }

            a#current {
                color: #BC1515;
                background-color: #EFEFEF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php
                $pages = array("How to do this", "How to do that", "How did you do this", "How did you do that", "Why did you do that", "Why did you do this");
                $currentID = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0);

                foreach($pages as $key => $value) {
                    $key = $key + 1;
                    print('<li><a href="index.php?page=category&id=' . $key . '"' . ($currentID == $key ? ' id="current"' : '') . '>' . $value . '</a></li>');
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

### The results

[image: Highlighted link has a slightly grayer background and red text]

As you can see, the highlighted link has a slightly gray background and red text. If you switch to another category, it will highlight that instead when you're on that page.

Hopefully this helped you with the highlights.

**EDIT:** This is the MySQL version of the same code, should run the same way :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: #151515;
            }

            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }

            li {
                margin: 15px;
            }

            a {
                padding: 5px 10px;
                color: #151515;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a:hover {
                color: #FEFEFE;
                background-color: #151515;
            }

            a#current {
                color: #BC1515;
                background-color: #EFEFEF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php
                include("admin/db.php");

                echo('<div class="rmm"><ul id="nav">
        <li class="home"><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="aboutus.php"><span>About Us</span></a></li>');

                $currentID = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category`";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo('<li><a href="category.php?id=' . $row['cid'] . '"' . ($currentID == $row['cid'] ? ' id="current"' : '') . '>' . $row['cname'] . '</a></li>');
                }

                echo('<li class="level2 nav-2-3-2"><a href="contactus.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li></ul></div>');
            ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited the post, try now :-)

Comment: Also, as for what goes to @RohanKumar's code; JavaScript is not a good way to mark something active, because not all clients have JavaScript enabled in their browser. By making it pure HTML, this way the active view is guaranteed and there is no need for JavaScript, nor an external library such as jQuery (keep in mind, that linking external libraries will also increase page load the same way as CSS imports).

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to, you could mark the answer you find the most useful as 'accepted' so that people can see that you've found a working solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**CSS**

```
<style>
  .li_active{
      background:#FF0;  
  }
</style>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    include("admin/db.php");
    /** Add  different id's to each li */
    echo '<div class="rmm"><ul id="nav">
    <li id="index" class="home"><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li id="aboutus" class="about"><a href="aboutus.php"><span>About Us</span></a></li>';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM category WHERE 1";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<li id="category_'.$row["cid"].'" class="'.$row['cname'].'">
                <a href="category.php?id='.$row["cid"].'>'.$row['cname'].'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '<li id="contactus" class="level2 nav-2-3-2"><a href="contactus.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li></ul></div>';
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
/** Not his javascript should be written on php page here 
    we need the category id to make category li active */
$(function(){
    var url=window.location.href;
    if(url.indexOf('aboutus.php') !== -1){
        $('#aboutus').addClass('li_active');
    } else if(url.indexOf('contactus.php') !== -1){
        $('#contactus').addClass('li_active');
    } else if(url.indexOf('category.php') !== -1){
        var id = '<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '' ;?>';
        // check for id and li category id to make it active
        if(id && $('#category_'+id).length){
            $('#category_'+id).addClass('li_active');
        }
    } else {// make index page active by default
        $('#index').addClass('li_active');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This code works good.. But,by using this code all categories menu got hide and contact menu didn't get highlight...